# Undefined symbol: __isPlatformVersionAtLeast error after installing firebase library

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, swift5, xcode10.3

I got this error after installing firebase library before that the error did not exist. Later I check by removing firebase library, the bug still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Firebase require at least Xcode 11. More details in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).